# How to check which object in survived space?

Tags: java, memory, space

I use jconsole when I look at heap memory I see:

```
PS Eden, PS Survivor and PS Old Gen
```

Does it exist instrument to check which object went from PS Eden to PS Survivor ?

Answer (score 1):

[jvisualvm](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) might give you what you're looking for. It ships with newer versions of the SDK.

Comment: I know jvisulvam but I never seen possibility to check which objects went to survived